# Big blank space at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having this problem, when I added a background image to a flexbox column, I can see that there is a big blank space at the bottom at the bottom. I tried to inspect the page but could not find the problem. I have no idea how to fix the problem, what I want to do is remove the blank space or make the picture go down all the way.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.row {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 3em;
    padding-left: 15em;
}
.row1 {
    flex: 50%;
}
.row-text-top {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 21px;
}
.row-text-mid {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.row-text-mid1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    border-left: 5px solid #ff9b7c;
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}
.row-text-low {
    padding-top: 3em;
}
.row1 {
    background-image: url(earth.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>City</title>
        <link href="wwd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Overview</h1>
                <div class="row-text-top">
                    One of the most urgent issues of our time, climate change has widespread                     implications — from the exacerbation of 
                    poverty, to the breakdown of infrastructure, to the loss of                                 environmental, political, economic and social security. 
                    Experts agree that climate change threatens to set back development                         efforts by decades, placing least developed countries 
                    and already-vulnerable populations in an even more precarious position.
                </div>
                <div class="row-text-mid">
                    The latest Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change (IPCC) Fifth                           Assessment Report (AR5), signed 
                    off by almost 200 nations, concludes with 95% certainty or more that                         humans have caused the majority 
                    of climate change since the 1950s. It predicts global surface                               temperature to continue to rise, along 
                    with increased sea level rise, melting of glaciers and ice sheets,                           acidification of oceans, increase 
                    in the intensity of tropical storms and changes in precipitation                             patterns.
                </div>
                <div class="row-text-mid1">
                    In other words; the science on climate change is clearer than ever, and                     so is the urgency for human action.
                </div>
                <div class="row-text-low">
                    As a global community, we all have a role in developing and implementing                     solutions toward significant 
                    transformation in our development patterns. It requires not only a shift                     in awareness and accountability 
                    for our own individual choices but in a social, political and economic                       shift towards enabling conditions 
                    for these sustainable choices to be made– and in turn, a more just,                         equal and healthy planet.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's a bit hard to see because of the image not being there but I will add a picture as well:

[image]

Comment: Which space do you mean?

Comment: if you mean the space you see at the bottom below the image from the image of your page, that is not part of your flexbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```css
.row {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 3em;         <---- This line
  padding-left: 15em;
}
```

You're adding additional padding all around the row element, including the bottom. After removing this padding, the space at the bottom of the screen is gone.

**Here's a working demo: https://codepen.io/Lissy93/pen/yLvBJLe**

Tip: I recommend using the developer tools, with the element selector you can hover over the space, and it will show exactly which element is causing it, and show whether it is (green for) padding and (orange for) margin.

Comment: I tried this but it made the gap even bigger, when I went into inspect mode on my browser the padding was not showing under the picture.

Comment: I think this is because the content is shorter than the length of the page.... I can provide a working code pen, if you'd like?

Comment: Here's a working demo: https://codepen.io/Lissy93/pen/yLvBJLe 

But I think I can improve on this further, if you'd like me to, as in it's current state it isn't at all responsive (meaning it will only work on your screen size). I recommend learning more about various layout techniques, to be able to make better use of [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), then [grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Thank you for your time! But for some reason there is still blank space at the bottom, its driving me crazy. I even tried copying ur code right off but still blank space...

Comment: Is it blank for you in the demo? I am 99% certain that this is just because the content is shorter than your page (try resizing the window, or adding more content). But you can check this yourself with the [dev tools's box model selectors](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/#box-model) - it will show weather the space is padding, margin, or (most likely) nothing.

Comment: @fnostro - That's on the left of the screen, not the bottom. But either way, it's not a good method layout, since it's not going to be responsive.

Comment: @Lissy93 my mistake, I added a comment to the wrong post.  In any event the spacing the OP is talking about is outside the flex area. They're looking in the wrong spot.

Comment: That is not really a problem what the question Owner @JohannesFerenius has. That deepends from content length and the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

View this snippet fullscreen. The dashed red border is the limit of your flexbox.  The space below the image (based on your image) is elsewhere.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border: 5px dashed red;
}

.row {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 3em;
  /* padding-left: 15em;*/
}

.row1 {
  flex: 50%;
}

.row-text-top {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.row-text-mid {
  padding-bottom: 3em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.row-text-mid1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  border-left: 5px solid #ff9b7c;
  padding: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}

.row-text-low {
  padding-top: 3em;
}

.row1 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>City</title>
  <link href="wwd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Overview</h1>
      <div class="row-text-top">
        One of the most urgent issues of our time, climate change has widespread implications — from the exacerbation of poverty, to the breakdown of infrastructure, to the loss of environmental, political, economic and social security. Experts agree that climate
        change threatens to set back development efforts by decades, placing least developed countries and already-vulnerable populations in an even more precarious position.
      </div>
      <div class="row-text-mid">
        The latest Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change (IPCC) Fifth Assessment Report (AR5), signed off by almost 200 nations, concludes with 95% certainty or more that humans have caused the majority of climate change since the 1950s. It predicts global
        surface temperature to continue to rise, along with increased sea level rise, melting of glaciers and ice sheets, acidification of oceans, increase in the intensity of tropical storms and changes in precipitation patterns.
      </div>
      <div class="row-text-mid1">
        In other words; the science on climate change is clearer than ever, and so is the urgency for human action.
      </div>
      <div class="row-text-low">
        As a global community, we all have a role in developing and implementing solutions toward significant transformation in our development patterns. It requires not only a shift in awareness and accountability for our own individual choices but in a social,
        political and economic shift towards enabling conditions for these sustainable choices to be made– and in turn, a more just, equal and healthy planet.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row1">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any space on the bottom. I using firefox on linux.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.row {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 3em;
    padding-left: 15em;
}
.row1 {
    flex: 50%;
}
.row-text-top {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 21px;
}
.row-text-mid {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.row-text-mid1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    border-left: 5px solid #ff9b7c;
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}
.row-text-low {
    padding-top: 3em;
}
.row1 {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/200);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
        <div class="main">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Overview</h1>
                <div class="row-text-top">
                    One of the most urgent issues of our time, climate change has widespread                     implications — from the exacerbation of 
                    poverty, to the breakdown of infrastructure, to the loss of                                 environmental, political, economic and social security. 
                    Experts agree that climate change threatens to set back development                         efforts by decades, placing least developed countries 
                    and already-vulnerable populations in an even more precarious position.
                </div>
                <div class="row-text-mid">
                    The latest Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change (IPCC) Fifth                           Assessment Report (AR5), signed 
                    off by almost 200 nations, concludes with 95% certainty or more that                         humans have caused the majority 
                    of climate change since the 1950s. It predicts global surface                               temperature to continue to rise, along 
                    with increased sea level rise, melting of glaciers and ice sheets,                           acidification of oceans, increase 
                    in the intensity of tropical storms and changes in precipitation                             patterns.
                </div>
                <div class="row-text-mid1">
                    In other words; the science on climate change is clearer than ever, and                     so is the urgency for human action.
                </div>
                <div class="row-text-low">
                    As a global community, we all have a role in developing and implementing                     solutions toward significant 
                    transformation in our development patterns. It requires not only a shift                     in awareness and accountability 
                    for our own individual choices but in a social, political and economic                       shift towards enabling conditions 
                    for these sustainable choices to be made– and in turn, a more just,                         equal and healthy planet.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hm, weird. Do you have any idea why it might be so?

Comment: @JohannesFerenius Could it be that you mean the space between bottom the text/image container to the bottom the page?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean and I dont know how to get rid of it.

Comment: @JohannesFerenius Add `.row, .row1 {
  height: 100vh;
}` to your style.